# Spring 6 -PropertyBatchUpdateException - no matching editors or conversion strategy found error for class HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am creating a `RestTemplate` bean which internally using `org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` class.

After migrating to Spring 6 - while creating bean of `HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory` class I am getting below error.

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.PropertyBatchUpdateException: Failed properties: Failed to convert property value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.Duration' for property 'connectTimeout'; Cannot convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type 'java.time.Duration' for property 'connectTimeout': no matching editors or conversion strategy found
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:135)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractPropertyAccessor.setPropertyValues(AbstractPropertyAccessor.java:79)
```

context.xml file

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
  <constructor-arg>
      <bean class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
          <constructor-arg>
              <bean class="MyHttpClientFactory">
                  <property name="keepAliveMS" value="${keepalive:300000}"/>
              </bean>
          </constructor-arg>
          <property name="connectTimeout" value="${connectTimeout:5000}"/>
    </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Migratiing from which version? Also if you are using Spring Boot why do you have XML configuration and not Java? Spring 6 introduced a `setConnectTimout(Duration)` which I suspect the XML is now picking instead of the `setConnectTimeout(int)`.

Comment: I have migrated from spring 5 to spring 6 and spring boot 2 - springboot 3
using xml configuration to add different time out value for different type of rest call

Comment: You don't need XML configuration for that, you can do the same in Java with a lot more ease.

Comment: ok but I need configure using xml.

Comment: As you are using Spring Boot try chaning the `5000` to `5S` and `300000` to `300S` or `5M`. I also assume that you are properly letting Spring Boot load this and now hack around this yourself?

Comment: Faling with same exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my context file as below-

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
  <constructor-arg>
      <bean class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
          <constructor-arg>
              <bean class="MyHttpClientFactory">
                  <property name="keepAliveMS" value="${keepalive:300000}"/>
              </bean>
          </constructor-arg>
          <property name="connectTimeout" >
        <bean class="java.time.Duration" factory-method="ofMillis">
            <constructor-arg value="${connectTimeout:5000}"/>
        </bean>
        </property>
    </bean>
  </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```